# Error Segmentation fault al escribir en archivo

Tags: c++

Qué tal a todos. Espero puedan apoyarme, estoy programando en C++ y obtengo el error de Segmentation fault al intentar escribir en un archivo.

```
//Buffer de caracteres
char buffer[1024];
if (this->getUnits() == "m")
{
    //Obtiene el tamaño total en bytes del archivo
    mbr.mbr_tamano = 1024*1024*this->getTamano();

    //Se llena el buffer de entrada
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        buffer[i] = '\0';

    //Se llena el archivo con el buffer de entrada
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getTamano()*1024; i++)
        fwrite(&buffer,1024,1,archivo);

    fclose(archivo);
}
```

En el segundo for, al intentar escribir sobre el archivo me lanza el error. Se me pide crear el archivo con un tamaño especificado por el usuario y este debe llenarse con el caracter \0.

De antemano agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: ¿Dónde defines la variable `archivo` y dónde abres el archivo?

Comment: Nos falta información para poder ayudarte. Por cierto, `fwrite` y `fclose` son funciones de C. Considera usar [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) en su lugar.